# How to move a Raphael canvas wholly (which contains some objects) from one coordinate to another coordinate to some other coordinate continuously

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, raphael

I have created Raphael content here ..   http://jsfiddle.net/ryWH3/76/

Now I need to move the whole content of Raphael Canvas from one
co-ordinate to another co-ordinate.

For Example:

My Raphael Canvas is at -- x_coordinate:100,y_coordinate:100

Now I want to move it to -- x: 200, y :200

From the old co-ordinates I want to move that whole content to -- x:150, y:150

again to some other co-ordinates from the last co-ordinates

Please suggest me in moving this content

Comment: Can you not move it in the html?

Comment: I tried with some animation like this

r.set(bigCircles, smallCircles, Text).animate({ transform: "t50,120" }, 1000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I don't think you can actually more the paper itself, which is what is returned by Raphael to your r variable. You can iterate over the elements and do whatever you like to them:

```
r.forEach(function (el) {
   el.translate(200,200);
});
```

I updated your fiddle to demonstrate it moving:

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryWH3/94/)

**EDIT**

I have also added the following to demonstrate animating your various sets:

```
Text.animate({transform: "t100,100"}, 1000);
smallCircles.animate({transform: "t100,100"}, 1000);
bigCircles.animate({transform: "t100,100"}, 1000);
```

[updated fiddle with above animation](http://jsfiddle.net/ryWH3/97/)

Comment: Hi Neil,
I am able to move like what you did.after translating to coordinates--(200,200),i want to move them to other coordinate like(200,250) after this again to some other coordinate (300,340) etc.. I want to move them continously to particular coordinates.Could you please help me in this...

Thanks,

Nagarjuna

Comment: Ya i accept it.you have given the good answer only.Thats why iam asking you for further help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

using jquery for example...

```
$(paper.canvas).css({top:topPosition, left: leftPosition});
```

The paper.canvas is how you get a hold of the dom element its within.